# how to disable automatic dot after number when using "ABC" input source?

Tags: input-source

**To reproduce the problem**

please do the following:

1. open TextEdit.app to write a number, e.g. `1`.
2. ensure you have switched to the one of the following input source: `U.S.`, `ABC` and `ABC-Extended`.
3. press the space twice and you will see the dot `.` was added after the number automatically.

The effect is like the following:

```
1. |
```

The token `|` marks where the cursor is.

**System environment**

MacOS Monterey Version 12.0.1

**Puzzle**

How can I disable the automatic dot adding? I just want to add `.` by myself when it's necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a system preference …

From Ventura onwards - Apple menu > System Settings > Keyboard

Up to Monterey - System Preferences > Keyboard > Text

Disable "Add full stop [period] with double-space"

[image]